# Vertically sliding list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
     <li>4</li>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function scroll() {
        $('#wrapper li:first').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, function() {
            $(this).show().parent().append(this);
        });
    }
    setInterval(scroll, 2000);
});
```

But it doesn't move that seamlessly. For example, the three last list items doesnt start sliding until the top one is gone.

I would like to have exactly this movement, except controlled my setInterval instead of a button click:
http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/totem/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this way once

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        function scroll() {
          var $li = $('#wrapper li');
          $li.eq(0).insertAfter($li.last())
        }
        setInterval(scroll, 2000);
      });
```

I think u will add a button to control the sliding up animation so for that you just need to add onclick evnet on that button like the bellow

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        function scroll() {
          var $li = $('#wrapper li');
          $li.eq(0).insertAfter($li.last())
        }
        $('#btn').on('click',scroll);
  });
```

Comment: I rather not use a button and would also like a sliding animation

Answer (score 0):

The totem jQuery plugin already uses an interval to control scrolling. You might simply set the start/stop button options to `null` if you do not want to use them. Which is even done by default for you:

```
$(function(){
    $('#wrapper').totemticker({
        speed:2000
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess here is what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function scroll() {
        $('#wrapper li:first').slideUp("slow", function() {
            $(this).show().parent().append(this);
        });
    }
    setInterval(scroll, 2000);
});
```

Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/qz6takb4/

Comment: This is what i had to start with. Only thing I want differently is that "1" is also sliding up when the rest is